# Change page title on Dynamics 365 Portal

Tags: dynamics-crm, portal, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-portals

I'm wondering how to change the title, as in `<title></title>` of a page in Dynamics?

I tried changing the website name but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Portal -> Web pages` navigation, open your portal entity page (Is Root = No) & modify the `Title` field value.

[Reference](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/248161)

Comment: Thanks Arun. This worked, but I still get the default name of the site appended after the custom title. For example, now it shows "My custom title - Customer Service Portal". Any ideas how to get rid of the last part?

Answer (score 4):

The title is the combination of:

1. The `Title` of the current web page, or the `Name` of the current web page when the `Title` is empty
2. The `Value` of the content snippet named `Browser Title Suffix`

Update these values accordingly.

Comment: Browser Title Suffix content snippet where is it used in code? .I have set the title of web page in localized content page and the value for content snippet is {{page.title}} what this causes is duplication of page title on navigation. Whenever I set it to empty then the title of my webpage get's overriden by web page path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Issue. I have modified the Title name in content file. Go to your web page-> localized content->select the content page->change the title.